# Vue3 Composition API PerfectScrollbar Plugin no element is specified to initialize

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, perfect-scrollbar

I'm trying to create a [Perfect Scrollbar](https://github.com/mdbootstrap/perfect-scrollbar) plugin for Vue3 but i'm stuck on an error when i initialize the object:

> Error: no element is specified to initialize PerfectScrollbar

Scrollbar component:

```
import PerfectScrollbar from 'perfect-scrollbar'
import { isEmpty } from 'lodash'
import {
 onMounted,
 reactive,
 ref,
 h
} from 'vue'

export default {
  name: 'VuePerfectScrollbar',
  props: {
    options: {
      type: Object,
      required: false,
      default: () => {
      }
    },
    tag: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
      default: 'div'
    }
  },
  setup(props, {emit, slots}) {
    const el = ref(null)
    let ps = reactive({})
    
    onMounted(() => {
      if (isEmpty(ps)) {
        ps = new PerfectScrollbar(el, props.options)

      }
    })


    return () => h(
      props.tag,
      {
        class: 'ps',
        ref: el
      },
      slots.default && slots.default()
    )
  }
}
```

I did a console.log right before the initialization and the element reference is there, so i'm not sure why the error pops up. According to [this](https://github.com/mdbootstrap/perfect-scrollbar/issues/769) `This error simply means that you are calling PerfectScrollbar on something that doesn't exist!` so maybe the DOM hasn't been updated at that moment? I tried with nextTick too but it didn't work.

Comment: what does `if (isEmpty(ps)) {` do?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim, i forgot to add the lodash import. It is a lodash function to check the object state. On the second line of setup i declare a ps reactive empty object and later on the create method i update it with the new PerfectScrollbar object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get access to the `value` attribute in the ref property as follows :

```
ps = new PerfectScrollbar(el.value, props.options)
```

Comment: damn... and i knew that one but i keep forgetting it... thank you